# Objective-C Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: mysql, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use the mySQL C Connector in Objective-C, but when I run the app in xcode i get the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/NAME/Documents/GITHUB/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/NAME/Documents/GITHUB/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mysql_close", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLManager disconnectFromServer] in APmySQLManager.o
  "_mysql_error", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLManager handlemySQLError] in APmySQLManager.o
  "_mysql_fetch_field", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLQueryHelper getFieldsForResult:] in APmySQLQueryHelper.o
  "_mysql_fetch_row", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLQueryHelper queryWithRawQuery:] in APmySQLQueryHelper.o
  "_mysql_free_result", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLQueryHelper queryWithRawQuery:] in APmySQLQueryHelper.o
  "_mysql_init", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLManager connectWithServer:database:port:username:password:] in APmySQLManager.o
  "_mysql_num_fields", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLQueryHelper queryWithRawQuery:] in APmySQLQueryHelper.o
  "_mysql_query", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLQueryHelper queryWithRawQuery:] in APmySQLQueryHelper.o
  "_mysql_real_connect", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLManager connectWithServer:database:port:username:password:] in APmySQLManager.o
  "_mysql_server_init", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLManager init] in APmySQLManager.o
  "_mysql_stat", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLManager isConnectedToServer] in APmySQLManager.o
  "_mysql_use_result", referenced from:
      -[APmySQLQueryHelper queryWithRawQuery:] in APmySQLQueryHelper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You need to link the proper MySQL framework/library to your project.

Comment: How do I do that? It's library path already points to the MySQL library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL library doesn't have x86_64 architecture support. You need to get library that is build against this architecture.

Or

You can run directly on device it will work with device. :)

Comment: What architecture do I need to use then? what do you mean by run on device? Like run on an actual phone device as opposed to a simulator?

Comment: Simulators run on different architecture phone use ARM architecture. Your sql library is not sliced for simulator architecture but it'll work for phone